# Participle as Adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs, participles

### Is it possible (and common) to use a participle as an adverb?

Examples:

- The damp walls ***looming overgrown*** and ruggedly out of the water bear witness to ancient grandeur. (In this case, the adverb participle to focus on is *overgrown*.)
- He ***went*** home ***smiling***. (Notice, there is no comma here indicating a participle construction, just an adverb.)

---

**On a side note:**
Not sure, if I can omit the relative pronoun in the first example, depending on how *defining* the relative clause/participle construction is to the sentence (which walls?). But that's another question and not important here as it would render the whole post too broad.

Comment: ***looming overgrown and ruggedly*** isn't particularly idiomatic, and by the time you tack on the additional adverbial element ***out of the water*** you've moved a very long way from "normal" English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How would a native speaker structure this sentence? The text is supposed to be literary (which is probably a bullshit idea on its own as a non-native speaker who has to ask about every little detail), so it's not meant to be oral/everyday language, but as an introduction into a (literary) text. But of course, it shouldn't sound like garbage or foreign (because it takes place in America and from a native speaker's perspective).

Comment: There's no omission of a relative pronoun in your first example. "Looming overgrown and ruggedly out of the water" is a gerund-participial clause modifying "damp walls". In your second example "smiling" is a depictive adjunct referring to the subject "he".